# HLS player is not streaming

Tags: ios, swift, stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a stream url which is getting from server. The streaming url is working in android and web, but whenever I try to play that ham getting a black screen with certain errors

`Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe6bcae2170 {Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12939 "byte range and no content length - error code is 200" UserInfo={NSDescription=byte range and no content length - error code is 200`

this the only thing I got from the server team

`like this server team told me like content type is not video/mp4. It is application/x-mpegURL and video/MP2T`

can you please help me out?